# Mysql_ubuntu_ERROR 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> delimiter &&
mysql> create procedure get()
    -> begin
    -> select * from a;
    -> end&&
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'get()
> begin
> select * from a;
> end' at line 1

```
mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_data |
+----------------+
| a              |
| test           |
+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `GET` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-G) in MySql, and therefore cannot be used as an object name without using backticks.

The following will work:

```
delimiter &&
create procedure `get`()
begin
select * from a;
end&&
delimiter ;
```

Alternatively, use another name for the procedure (which would be my recommendation as using reserved words as object names is unwise).